# Is it ok to change table caption depending on user choices?

Tags: tables, screen-reader

I have a table listing available jobs. By default this table shows all jobs. The table caption is now "Available jobs". If the user make use of the filter functionality the result is filtered and the caption changes to "Result of available jobs filtered by search criteria" (translated so might not be correct english).

Is it nescassary for the caption to be this descriptive and adaptable to changes or is the first title always enough? The reason to use caption in this case is primarily for thoose who use assistive devices, like screen readers.

Comment: Depending on the technical solution (site reload or dynamic change) for changing the tables content screen readers automatically start from the beginning therefore can read the updated table caption. ([Check these guidelines on how to handle dynamic content](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php))

Answer (score 1):

If you're already concerned about screen readers, all the better.

Depending on the design, the filter might be *after* the title in the screen reading sequence. In that case, changing the title will not be taken up by the screen reader, since they usually operate from the focus point onwards. Hence, the people for whom you added the title will never see (or hear) it change.

I'd leave the title unchanged.